# glutCreateWindow on multi gpu system

Tags: opengl, glut, freeglut, glew

I use `GLUT` to create window (`glutCreateWindow()`). It seems like glut creates window allways in monitor which is in Windows set as MAIN. In my system are two GPUs.

Is it possible to set which monitor, resp. which GPU use to create window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with a [stock](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/spec3.html) GLUT implementation.

Comment: is it possible with freeglut?

Answer (score 2):

On a Mac, you can use CGLSetVirtualScreen(CGLCurrentContext(),x); where x is 0, 1 or 2 (usually GPU 1, GPU 2 and Apple Software).  But, you may have to add a flag to your applications' Info.plist file to enable multi-GPU support for this to work.  See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1734/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010791